# AsyncStorage setItem inside loop

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Is it ideal to `setItem` inside a loop? Assuming that i retrieved a list of data from the backend, which i need to do some heavy processing on each data before i can store it individually inside AsyncStorage store.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";


async function getList(query){
  /* some call setup in here */

    try {
        const response = await fetch(/* call parameters in here */);
        const { data, err } = response;
        if (err) throw new Error(err.message);

        await processAndStoreItems(data);
        return data;
    } catch(err){
        throw err;
    }
}


async function processAndStoreItems(data){
    /* data is a list of array that needs to be processed first before storing */
    data.forEach( d => {
        /* Some processing of data happening in here, and it may be a heavy processing that may take time */
        const { processedKey, processedData } = await heavyProcessingHere(d);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(processedKey, JSON.stringify(processedData));
    });
}
```

The reason why i did this was because, some of the process may take longer time, and the idea to just wait the whole process to finish then only store isn't ideal, since there might be case where user will logout from the app while the whole process is still running, and i need to clear the stored items upon logout.

If i do `setItem` inside loop, at least i can be assured that the store will always be updated for any completed processed data, and i can just delete whatever that is already stored on logout, rather than waiting for the whole process to complete, then only store it in AsyncStorage, which will be a problem if the user logout while the process is still incomplete, leaving the store outdated and making deletion hard for those items that are still in process.

So i need to know if performance wise, using `setItem` inside loop is okay? I read from somewhere about people facing crash issue with AsyncStorage when attempting to use `setItem` inside loop, which is bad for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not putting your array to cookie

Like this;

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataArray, JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I need to process each data, and the returned processed data is different for each data, thats why i need to keep track of every processed data in the form of `{ processedkey1 : processeddata1, processedkey2: processeddata2 }` . The heavy processing function that processes the data can be blocking especially when the processing time is long, which is why i opted to do `setItem` on loop instead of waiting for everything to finish then `setItem` at the end of loop.